# Photon Unity Leaderboard sorting

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, leaderboard, photon

I am trying to get the scores of the players in multiplayer mode using Photon Unity Networking.

```
PhotonNetwork.playerList[i].GetScore();
```

I use the above line to get the scores of all the players in the room currently.

I added the Player Name and Score to a dictionary like this,
 1. Player Name as "Key".
 2. Player Score as "Value".

```
for(int i = 0; i < PhotonNetwork.playerList.Length; i++)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey (PhotonNetwork.playerList[i].name))
    {
        dict[PhotonNetwork.playerList[i].name] = PhotonNetwork.playerList[i].GetScore();
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add (PhotonNetwork.playerList[i].name, PhotonNetwork.playerList[i].GetScore());
    }
}
```

After this, I wanted the top 5 scores and the names in descending order. 
So, I sorted the dictionary and took the top 5 values like this,

```
foreach(var item in dict.OrderByDescending(r => r.Value).Take(5))
{
    scoreText.text = item.Key +" "+ item.Value;
}
```

Output required is "The sorted 5 elements in the dictionary" Please help me to find the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: "I am not getting the proper output" is not a very precise description, as nearly all outputs fit this description. You need to be a lot more specific than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this line of code:

```
var sortedPlayerList = (from p in playerList orderby p.GetMyScore() descending select p).ToList();
```

It will sort an array with descending, and you can show top 5 players like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // show your player's score
}
```